# jQuery skip div within a sequence

Tags: jquery, html, show-hide, visible, skip

I have the following:

**CSS**

```
.sequence-container div {display:none;}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.sequence-container div:first').show();

$('.next').click(function() {
  var $next = $('.sequence-container div:visible').next();
  var $page = $('.sequence-container div:visible').attr("id");
}
```

I have a series of `divs'

```
<div class='sequence-container'></div>
<div class='sequence-container'></div>
<div class='sequence-container'></div>
```

The code works well, all `DIVS` are hidden, on page load, the first div is shown and then when a user clicks a button, the jQuery is fired to show the next div and so on.

However, what I am struggling with is how to `skip` a div:

```
$next = $('.sequence-container div:visible').next();
```

I sometimes need it to be the div **after** the next div if that makes sense.  Is that possible and any suggestions on where to start?

Comment: `$next = $next.next();`

Comment: Could you make a sample on jsbin.com or similar service? If you just write some notes in the html of what you need to happen, it would be a lot easier to solve.

Comment: @tymeJV - surely not that simple?

Comment: How could it not be that simple? It IS that simple :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7UNuw/

Comment: @tymeJV - pop that down as an answer and I'll mark as accepted - thank you very very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do

```
$next = $next.next();
```

.